# 400 bad request ngnix-gunicorn django

Tags: django, nginx, django-admin, gunicorn

I havw been using gunicorn to run django project and using ngix to serve static files. But when I try to update or write using django admin interface,  I am getting 400 bad request error. After reading from answers I added allowed domian in settings file. But still the problem persists.  Please any one provide solution for this.

Comment: Can you put `DEBUG = True` in your settings file and post the error here? or post the content of the gunicorn and nginx log files?

Comment: I am not getting any message , I am getting only blank white page with message as Bad request (404 ).

Comment: What's the content of `/var/log/nginx/nginx_error.log` ?

Comment: Nothing is there in the log, it is blank. Can please tell what are steps to be followed in order to run the website using Nginx and gunicorn. Please

Comment: I had same issue. Nothing in logs. In the end it was allowed hosts list problem since I needed separate entries for www.domain.com and domain.com